# Django CheckConstraint not enforcing check on model field

Tags: django, sqlite, django-models, django-testing, referential-integrity

I am using Django 3.2.

Backend database used for testing: **sqlite3**

I have a model Foo:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    # some fields ...
    some_count = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        models.constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(
                check = ~models.Q(some_count=0), 
                name = 'check_some_count',
            ),
        ]
```

I also have a unit test like this:

```
def test_Foo_some_count_field_zero_value(self):
    # Wrap up the db error in a transaction, so it doesn't get percolated up the stack
    with transaction.atomic():
        with self.assertRaises(IntegrityError) as context:
            baker.make(Foo, some_count=0)
```

When my unit tests are run, it fails at the test above, with the error message:

```
    baker.make(Foo, some_count=0)
AssertionError: IntegrityError not raised
```

I then changed the `CheckConstraint` attribute above to:

```
    class Meta:
        models.constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(
                check = models.Q(some_count__lt=0) | models.Q(some_count__gt=0), 
                name = 'check_some_count',
            ),
        ]
```

The test still failed, with the same error message. I then tried this to check if constraints were being enforced at all:

```
def test_Foo_some_count_field_zero_value(self):
    foo = baker.make(Foo, some_count=0)
    self.assertEqual(foo.some_count, 0)
```

To my utter dismay, the test passed - clearly showing that the constraint check was being ignored. I've done a quick lookup online to see if this is a known issue with sqlite3, but I haven't picked up anything on my radar yet - so why is the constraint check being ignored - and how do I fix it (without overriding `models.Model.clean()` ) ?

Comment: what does `sqlmigrate <migration-name>`  says?

Comment: I noticed that it appears that no migrations were being generated for it, so I commented it out and run `makemigrations` and I got the message 'No changes detected.'. I uncommented the section, and still 'No changes detected'.

Comment: perhaps you should look to the migration file where the check was introduced, and remove the check there.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try `constraints` not `models.constraints`

```
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            ...
        ]
```